# jQuery + Testing Element Values (expansion)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, object

So, I have a structure I'm editing that involves a `Javascript Object` called **bulk**.

I have it functional (with some bugs), but I feel I'm doing too much `DOM` manipulation. The problem is **hard-coded** values with my `jQuery`.

I won't post all of the code here, but just what I'm concerned with:

**(full code in this fiddle if interested - http://jsfiddle.net/G689t)**

Let me list basic parameters, so it makes sense:

- You have a `capacity` of `10`.
- When you select `checkboxes`, it to logically identifies which `checkbox`'s are affordable and disables the ones that aren't.
- It *also* needs to remove the `disabled` status if the `checkbox` is *unselected*.
- `speed` counter alters our total `capacity` by `-/+` 1 based on a tier from **1-4**.
- `speed` and `capacity` need to communicate for the **UI** experience.

I've written a `function` that accomplishes this, but I just feel as if the `DOM` is being manipulated too much with my code.

Can somebody help with unifying this process into a singular `function` for **checking/updating `DOM`** based on the values I've described?

- PC = Power Capacity **(capacity)**
- speed = Speed of character **(speed)**

Here is some code I've attempted (JS):

#### Data Structure:

```
var bulk = {
    speed: 1,
    damage: 0,
    type: 'P',
    statEf: [],
    health: 0,
    minion: [0],
    pc: 10,
    exp: 9000
};
```

#### Attempted Function

```
// CORE UPDATE FUNCTION FOR VALUES / DISABLE / ENABLE
$(':checkbox, input[type="button"]').on('click', function() {
    if(bulk.pc <= 1){
        $('#addSpeed').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        $('#remSpeed').removeAttr('disabled');
    } else if(bulk.speed > 2){
        $('#remSpeed').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
    if(bulk.pc <= 1 && bulk.pc !== 4){
        $('#remSpeed').removeAttr('disabled');
        $('#addSpeed').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
});
```

Should I just keep running with this and test every `value`, then toss it into my later `functions`, or is there an easier way to accomplish this?

The goal is to write **one** function that tests a few things:

- If the `checkbox['data-pc']` can't be afforded by `bulk.pc`, disable it **as long as** it isn't `checked`.
- If the `bulk.speed` is 1, disable the `remSpeed` button
- If the `bulk.speed` is 4, disable the `addSpeed` button

*(all of this is working, just need to know how to combine this into a single function)*

I was thinking a `switch case` with difficult `parameters`, but I'd appreciate a better option.

**(full code in this fiddle if interested - http://jsfiddle.net/G689t)**

**PS:** I was hoping somebody could look at the **fiddle** and easily **unite this into a single function**

**VALUES / DISABLE / ENABLE**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of thought (and a night of rest), I've come up with a **master DOM function** that seems to work flawlessly.

It really is a pity I didn't think about it earlier. The problem I was hitting was mapping everything to `if / else if / else` statements. Because of this, it was producing bugs and not firing all of the tests if one of them came back valid.

Without further delay, the solution was:

#### Full Code Here: http://jsfiddle.net/ZBGLb/1/

```
function updateDom(){
    if(bulk.pc < 1 || bulk.speed >= 4){
        $('#addSpeed').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
    if(bulk.speed <= 1){
        $('#remSpeed').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
    if(bulk.speed > 1){
        $('#remSpeed').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
    if(bulk.speed < 4 && bulk.pc > 0){
        $('#addSpeed').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
    $(":checkbox").each(function() {
        if($(this).data('pc') > bulk.pc && $(this).prop('checked')==false){
            $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        } else if ($(this).data('pc') <= bulk.pc) {
            $(this).removeAttr('disabled');
        }
    });
    for (var key in bulk) {
        $('#' + key).text(bulk[key]);
    };
}
```

**And to elaborate how it's used, for each function, I just run the `updateDom()` function during the appropriate calls where things may change.**

```
// ADD SPEED FUNCTION
$('#addSpeed').on('click', function() {
    bulk.speed += 1;
    bulk.pc -= 1;
    updateDom();
});

// REDUCE SPEED FUNCTION
$('#remSpeed').on('click', function() {
    bulk.speed -= 1;
    bulk.pc += 1;
    updateDom();
});
```

Now I have my data structure working and I can write the rest of the code to just manipulate the `object` without thinking about **static values** for `DOM Manipulation` scattered throughout my code.

#### Full Code Here: http://jsfiddle.net/ZBGLb/1/